# $C= \lbrace M \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R}): M^2 = -I_{2n}\rbrace$. Why $C= GL_{2n} (\mathbb{R}) \cdot \ J$, $J=\begin{bmatrix}0&-I_n\\I_n&0\end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C=\left\{M \in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R}): M^2 = -I_{2n}\right\}$. Why is $C = GL_{2n} (\mathbb{R}) \cdot \ J$ with $J=\begin{bmatrix}0&-I_n\\I_n&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $GL_{2n} (\mathbb{R} ) $ acting on $M_{2n} (\mathbb{R})$ by left multiplication?

This is a question from an exercise sheet of mine and I don't know how to proceed at all. Firstly, I have put an $\mathbb{C} $ - vector space structure on it by setting $(a+bi, v) = a+bMV$ and shown that the map $f(v) = Mv$ is linear with respect to this vector space. Moreover I know that a $\mathbb{C}$- basis ${v_1, \ldots, v_{2n}}$ corresponds to a real basis $\lbrace Mv_1, \ldots, Mv_{2n}, v_1, \ldots , v_{2n} \rbrace$. How do I proceed from this point on?

Comment: Not all non-singular multiples of $J$ are in $C$. Do you mean conjugates of $J$?

Comment: I corrected it. I should be $2n$. It should be.

Comment: But $J\in GL_{2n} (\mathbb{C})$, so $C = GL_{2n} (\mathbb{C}) J=GL_{2n} (\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Can you please explain what set you denote by $ GL_{2n} (\mathbb{C}) J$?

Comment: If $\mathbb{C}$ were $\mathbb{R}$ then $C$ would be the set of $GL(\mathbb{R})$ conjugates of $J$.

Comment: The coset by right multiplication. $\lbrace MJ : M \in GL_{2n} (\mathbb{C}) \rbrace$.

Comment: Then the assertion is plain wrong. $2J$ does not square to $-I$.

Comment: All elements of $C$ have minimal polynomial dividing $X^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question as set makes sense. As @Servaes points out you are asking for a proof that $C$ is the whole of $GL_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$ which it is not: as I commented above $2J\not\in C$.

Here is what I think is true.

Suppose $M\in M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $M^2=-I$. Then there is a matrix $P\in GL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $P^{-1}M P=\begin{pmatrix} O & -I_n\\I_n&O\end{pmatrix}$.

This is easily got from the Rational Canonical Form. The minimal polynomial of $M$ is $X^2+1$, which is irreducible. So the RCF of $M$ is a sum of $2\times 2$ blocks of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\1 &0\end{pmatrix}$. Re-arranging the basis gives what I have asserted.

*[In other words the matrices must be over $\mathbb{R}$ and the action of $GL$ on $J$ is conjugation not multiplication. If you insist on allowing $\mathbb{C}$ I think you'll find that the  matrix $\begin{pmatrix} i & 0\\0 &i\end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample to any adjustment you try to make to the question.]*